# What is annotation for ejb ref in ejb 3

Tags: annotations, ejb-3.0

In EJb 2.0, in the ejb-jar.xml, there used to be this entry:

```
<ejb-ref>
<ejb-ref-name>ejb/fooremote</ejb-ref-name>
<ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
<remote>test.FooRemoteIF</remote>
</ejb-ref>
```

In ejb3.0 with annotations, we have @Remote in place of `<remote>` and `@Stateless` for `<ejb-ref-type>.` But in the annotated bean interface I dont see any JNDI declarations for `<ejb-ref-name>`. So how will the client know the jndi name for the EJb interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@EJB(name="...")` is the equivalent of `<ejb-ref-name>`.  That said, if you annotate a field or method for injection, then you don't need to lookup stateless session beans at all.  You do still need the JNDI name for stateful session beans, so class-level `@EJB(name="...")` (possibly within an `@EJBs` if you have several) is my recommendation.

Comment: So if i annotate a bean with @Stateless, there is no need to supply  @EJB(name="...")? But how will the container register the EJb with the JNDI name if i dont supply one?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. The JNDI name of an *EJB reference*, which is relative to `java:comp/env`, is unrelated to the JNDI name of the *EJB itself*. In EJB 3.0, the JNDI name of an EJB itself and the mechanism for binding an EJB reference to an EJB are both vendor-specific.

Comment: If you can elaborate onthis a bit:That said, if you annotate a field or method for injection, then you don't need to lookup stateless session beans at all.Iam not able to understand tis.

Comment: `@EJB FooRemoteIF myEJBRef;` means you don't have to perform the lookup at all: the container will perform the lookup (or whatever it needs to do to resolve the reference), and then it will inject it into the field. That means you don't need to perform a lookup at all. Well, unless you need the reference in some unrelated piece of code, and in that case passing the EJB reference around is probably best (or using CDI, if your application server supports EE 6).